Aggregate into custom groups
I'm not sure if this can be done in one stored procedure. I got it working using nested views but I want it to be as concise as possible.
Every time I try to select from a subquery, I get errors that I can't debug. I understand the concepts of how to get an output but struggle with the syntax.
Suppose we have a large table listing every household in the United States in the following format:
[dbo].[US_HOUSEHOLDS_TABLE]



HOUSEHOLD_ID
FAMILY_NAME
MEMBER_NAME




1
Anderson
Robert


1
Anderson
Mary


1
Anderson
Cody


1
Anderson
Brittany


2
Carver
William


2
Carver
Suzanne


3
Washington
Fred


3
Washington
Ethel


3
Washington
Tony


4
Smith
Darlene


4
Smith
Amy


4
Smith
Richard



Desired output:



FAMILY_SIZE
FREQUENCY




1
23,903,124


2
57,116,548


3
38,617,295


4
12,397,106


5
3,108,284


6 or more
1,393,571




I'm sorry, the tables looked correct in the real time review but when I published it, the first table didn't format correctly.

Isn't that just a simple group by + count? Please show us your attempt that has errors.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You can do something like this perhaps:
SELECT  *
INTO #data
FROM    (
    VALUES  (1, N'Anderson', N'Robert')
    ,   (1, N'Anderson', N'Mary')
    ,   (1, N'Anderson', N'Cody')
    ,   (1, N'Anderson', N'Brittany')
    ,   (2, N'Carver', N'William')
    ,   (2, N'Carver', N'Suzanne')
    ,   (3, N'Washington', N'Fred')
    ,   (3, N'Washington', N'Ethel')
    ,   (3, N'Washington', N'Tony')
    ,   (4, N'Smith', N'Darlene')
    ,   (4, N'Smith', N'Amy')
    ,   (4, N'Smith', N'Richard')
    ,   (4, N'Smith', N'Darlene')
    ,   (4, N'Smith', N'Amy')
    ,   (4, N'Smith', N'Richard')
    ,   (5, 'Sigge', 'Mannen')
    ,   (5, 'Stack', 'Overflow')
    
) t (HOUSEHOLD_ID,FAMILY_NAME,MEMBER_NAME)

SELECT  CASE WHEN cnt < 6 THEN CAST(cnt AS VARCHAR(30)) ELSE '6 or more' END AS HouseHold
,   COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM    (
    SELECT  count(*) AS cnt
    FROM    #data
    GROUP BY HOUSEHOLD_ID
    ) x
GROUP BY CASE WHEN cnt < 6 THEN CAST(cnt AS VARCHAR(30)) ELSE '6 or more' END

First, you get the count by the household and then you group by that count.
Those with 6+ get their own group.
Outputs:



HouseHold
Total




2
2


3
1


4
1


6 or more
1




Perfect, thank you. I don't know why I have so much trouble with syntax with T-SQL. I know HOW to do what I want but when I try to code it, the debugging errors are so unhelpful and when I look at examples online, it seems it's exactly the same syntax yet it says it's wrong. I never had this much trouble coding.

@WannaKatana if you had posted the actual errors we could have help you understand them.
